# Dynamics cloud RetrieveRecordChangeHistory Data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, microsoft-dynamics

Any good ideas how to get record changes from Dynamics with data factory ?

This is as far as I have gotten:

Using the Dynamics connector and this is as far as I have gotten with googling

```
@concat('RetrieveRecordChangeHistory(Target=@Target)?@Target={%22accountid%22:%0000-000-000-0000-00000000%22,%22@odata.type%22:%22Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.account%22}')
```

but can't for some reason get the data out.

Has someone made it work ?

has anyone done something like that with data factory?

Comment: https://crmchap.co.uk/interacting-with-the-dynamics-365-common-data-service-web-api-from-azure-data-factory/ Hope you are able to follow these steps and do a basic web api call before running this crm function web api call? Any errors you are seeing?

Comment: Thanks for the link and instructions! Managed to get the authentication with linked services(rest) and it works as well. case closed.

Comment: Great to hear, glad to help. I’ll post it as answer - pls accept/upvote it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s no native way of interacting with Dynamics CRM/CDS REST web api from Azure data factory pipeline.

But we can setup the AAD app registration to get auth token, CRM application user and ADF web activity to hit the CRM web api successfully. [Read more](https://crmchap.co.uk/interacting-with-the-dynamics-365-common-data-service-web-api-from-azure-data-factory/)